# Why does integration by parts give the wrong answer to $\int xy dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrating directly: $$\int xydx = y \int x dx = y\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2}x^2 y$$

Now let's instead integrate using the integration by parts formula:
$$\int u dv = uv - \int v du$$

We have:
$$\int xydx = x^2y-\int x d(xy) = x^2y- \int x(xdy+ydx) = x^2 y-\int x^2 dy-\int xy dx = x^2y-x^2y-\frac{1}{2}x^2y = -\frac{1}{2}x^2 y$$

Which is almost the right answer, except that the sign is wrong.

> **Question.** What's going on here?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: y is constant here. So $dy=0$.

Comment: @Mesmerizedstudent, ah I see. Good point.

Comment: In the first integration you treat $y$ as a constant

Comment: $dy = 0 \implies\int xy\ dx = x^2y-\int x d(xy) = x^2y- \int x(x\ dy+y\ dx) = x^2 y-\int xy\ dx$ and $\int xy\ dx =  x^2 y-\int xy\ dx \implies 2\int xy\ dx =  x^2 y$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas, can you elaborate? In what sense do they differ by a constant?

Comment: @goblin, ignore my comment, it seems Doug M has found the error.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see what all the downvotes are for. This seems like a pretty subtle issue and consequently a very reasonable question. I strongly suspect that most of the downvoters cannot give a coherent mathematical viewpoint on the meaning of phrases like "$x$ is constant with respect to $y$" or "$y$ is allowed to vary as a function of $x$." And, I feel sorry for people with less confidence than me who try to use this site. They get all this disapproval and probably think the fault lies with themselves. Really, it is the attitudes of this community where the problems truly lie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y$ is constant here. So $dy=0$. At least that is the way you treat it in the first integration.

Answer (score 1):

If
$$\int xy~\mathrm{d}x \equiv \int u~\mathrm{d}v$$
Then
$$\begin{align*}u = x &\implies \mathrm{d}u = \mathrm{d}x\\
                \mathrm{d}v = y~\mathrm{d}x &\implies v = xy\end{align*}$$
Now
$$\int u~\mathrm{d}v = uv - \int v~\mathrm{d}u$$
Plug in the values from above
$$\int u~\mathrm{d}v = x \cdot xy - \int xy\cdot\mathrm{d}x = x^2y - \frac{1}{2}x^2y = \frac{1}{2}x^2y$$
Alternatively,
$$\begin{align*}u = xy &\implies \mathrm{d}u = y~\mathrm{d}x\\
                \mathrm{d}v = \mathrm{d}x &\implies v = x\end{align*}$$
$$\int u~\mathrm{d}v = xy \cdot x - \int x\cdot y~\mathrm{d}x = x^2y - \frac{1}{2}x^2y = \frac{1}{2}x^2y$$

Answer (score 1):

For $$\int xydx = y \int x dx = y\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2}x^2 y$$

You are assuming $y$ is a constant while for

$$\int xydx = x^2y-\int x d(xy) = x^2y- \int x(xdy+ydx) = x^2 y-\int x^2 dy-\int xy dx = x^2y-x^2y-\frac{1}{2}x^2y = -\frac{1}{2}x^2 y$$

You are assuming that $y$ depends on $x$

That is why you are getting differenet results.